# db_keep_cache_size in depreciated in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I'm trying to keep/pin frequently accessed table in buffer, but i see the db_keep_cache_size parameter is deprecated in 12c. is there any alternative way to perform same on 12c?

my oracle version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit.

I tried below steps in 12c and it executed without any error, but not sure it will have any impact on 12c.

1. show parameter keep;
2. alter system set db_keep_cache_size=1M scope=both;
3. show parameter keep;
4. SELECT SEGMENT_NAME, BUFFER_POOL from dba_segments where SEGMENT_NAME='cust_table' and owner='services';
5. alter TABLE services.cust_table storage (buffer_pool keep);

Could someone please suggest, whether above steps are valid in 12c?

Thanks in advance.
Laks

Comment: db_keep_cache_size is *not* deprecated: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DB_KEEP_CACHE_SIZE.html#GUID-E304447C-C9A1-4F58-97BE-75566754DA15

Comment: thanks for the reply, when i check in the gv$parameter, i see  buffer_pool_keep    ISDEPRECATED=True

Comment: Buffer_pool_keep is different parameter and it obsolete even in oracle 9i: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch118.htm

Comment: You specified db_keep_cache_size in this question and it's not deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  any alternative statement for "alter TABLE services.cust_table storage (buffer_pool keep);"  ?